# where are member-vars of a class on the heap stored?

Tags: c++

As a class is instantiated on the heap. Are all member vars then also allocated on the heap, or somewhere else. Is there then any good in allocating member vars explicit on the heap?

```
struct abc {
std::vector<int> vec;
}


int main() {
abc* ptr = new abc(); //the "class" is on the heap but where is vec?
ptr->vec.push_back(42); //where will the 42 be stored?
return 0;
}
```

will this make any difference

```
struct abc {
std::vector<int>* vec_ptr;
abc() { vec_ptr = nev std::vector<int>(); }

int main() {
abc* ptr = new abc();
ptr->vec->push_back(42);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? We might be able to help you better if we know that.

Comment: This is actually about storage duration. Standard C++ has no notion of stack or heap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When vectors are allocated, do they use memory on the heap or the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036474/when-vectors-are-allocated-do-they-use-memory-on-the-heap-or-the-stack)

Comment: @underscore_d how is that gonna work? The question was asked a full month before the question this is supposed to be a dup of.

Comment: I don't think it matters, if the other one provides more and better answers. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315472/old-question-marked-as-duplicate-of-a-new-question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-static data members are stored inside the object (class instance) they're part of.

If you create an object as a local with automatic storage duration, its members are 
inside it.  If you allocate an object dynamically, they're inside it. 
If you allocate an object using some entirely different allocation scheme, its members will still be inside it wherever it is.  An object's members are *part* of that object.

Note that here the `vector` instance here is inside your structure, but `vector` itself manages its own dynamic storage for the items you push into it.  So, the `abc` instance is dynamically allocated in the usual free store with its `vector` member inside it, and `42` is in a separate dynamic allocation managed by the `vector` instance.

For example, say vector is implemented like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class vector {
    T *data_ = nullptr;
    size_t capacity_ = 0;
    size_t used_ = 0;
    // ...
};
```

then `capacity_` and `used_` are both part of your vector object. The `data_` *pointer* is part of the object as well, but the memory managed by the vector (and *pointed at* by `data_`) is not.

---

### A note on terminology:

- *with automatic storage duration* was originally *on the stack*. As Loki points out (and I [mentioned myself elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182244/212858)), automatic local storage is often implemented using the call stack, but it's an implementation detail.
- *dynamically* was originally *on the heap* - the same objection applies.
- When I say *usual free store*, I just mean *whatever resource is managed by `::operator new`*. There could be anything in there, it's another implementation detail.

Comment: If possible, just use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck) or a checking malloc [eg](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html) before doing lots of speculative work.

Comment: Heap and stack are meaningless concepts when used in C++. They also make it harder to think and reason about C++ objects. Variables have storage duration and are stored in their containing context. This is how it is defined (in the standard) and if you think about it this way it simplifies everything.

Comment: @Useless: Suppose I have an object created on heap using new keyword. Then in this object, I create another object of another class without using new keyword. Will this create the second object on stack or heap?

Comment: Ask a question showing the specific example your have in mind. There are too many special cases to reasonably handle in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be simplified. Consider:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(42);
}
```

"Where is `42` stored?"

In this example, `v` is an automatic variable, so it is stored in the local scope's store (usually the stack). But note that `v` has a fixed, small size -- it's just the handler object. The actual memory for the contained elements is separately allocated by the vector's internal logic, using the specified allocator (in this case, `std::allocator`), which in turn takes all its memory from the free store.

All the (non-static) data members of a class form part of that class's data type and consume space -- this is essentially the same as a dumb C `struct`. However, the magic of most C++ library classes lies in the fact that their data members are only tiny pointers, and all the payload data is allocated separately and managed by the class's internal logic.

So when you make a class with lots of vector members, the class itself still won't be very big. Any instance of that class will be allocated in its entirety wherever and however you want it (automatically, dynamically, statically), but be aware that each member object will request additional, separate memory all by itself to do its work.

Answer (score 0):

the `new`ed object is treated as a contiguous allocation. creating a new instance of `abc` creates an allocation with a minimum size of `sizeof(abc)`.

the system does not allocate members of the class separately when you create via `new`. to illustrate: `new` does not call `new` for each member, sub-member. therefore, the data members are stored in the contiguous allocation created by `new`, which is a single allocation.

in the case of the `vector`, the vector internally uses dynamic allocation for its elements -- this is accomplished using a *separate* allocation. this allocation is made within vector's implementation.

therefore the members do reside on the heap, but they exist as part of the `abc` instance and that instance uses one allocation, excluding any allocations the data members create.

> Is there then any good in allocating member vars explicit on the heap?

yes. there are many reasons you might choose to do this. considering the context of the question: you should favor declaring your members as values until there is a very good reason not to ([details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871429/class-members-that-are-objects-pointers-or-not-c/3871597#3871597)). when you need to declare your member as a heap allocation, always use an appropriate container (e.g. auto pointer, shared pointer) because this will save you tons of effort, time, and complexity.