# Memory Allocation for Derived C++ classes

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am working on designing a small system and am wondering about a nuance of how memory is allocated for derived classes.

If I have two classes

```
class foo {
public: int a;
Foo(): a(0) {};
 };
class bar : public foo {
public: int b;
Bar() : Foo() , b(0) {}
};
```

and then do something like this in another method

```
Bar* purple = new Bar();
```

I know that both constructors will be called (for Foo and Bar) but how will the memory be allocated. Is the memory for both 'a' and 'b' allocated at the same time, as they are both a part of Bar class, or is the memory allocated for 'a' when the Foo constructor is called and the memory for 'b' allocated when the Bar constructor is called.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: All of the memory is allocated at once.

Comment: As an aside you should be using initializer syntax instead of assigning a and b in the body of the constructor.

Comment: Kate Gregory: Whoops, thank you for the heads up, should be fixed now

@Chad Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Bar` is just one contiguous allocation, as is `new Bar[n]`.

It may help to think of like this:

```
Bar* purple = new Bar();
```

is *similar* to:

```
Bar* purple = (Bar*)malloc(sizeof(Bar));
```

Behind the scenes, the constructor is also called, and in some cases the allocation may be greater than `sizeof(Bar)`; `new[]` is a common case where it is greater because the array's count is secretly stored in the allocation in many implementations.

**Update**

The sizeof `Bar` itself is the size required to store the type; its members, its bases, a pointer to its vtable, etc. - all with native alignment (by default). The compiler may also introduce padding.

Therefore, the single contiguous allocation will be sufficiently large enough to hold everything both foo and bar require, including `foo::a` and `bar::b`.

In more detail: [where are member-vars of a class on the heap stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626350/where-are-member-vars-of-a-class-on-the-heap-stored)

Comment: It should also be clarified that since `Bar` inherits from `foo`, it has all the members and functions that `foo` has, so that's why `sizeof(Bar)` is guaranteed to be big enough.

Answer (score 2):

The sizeof(bar) is sufficiently large such that it can contain sizeof(foo) and everything is allocated in once allocation request.