# Adding vector to 2D vector, and keeping reference to the last vector

Tags: c++

I am writing a program and there was a very subtle error that was hard to recognize.

I examined the program for hours and it looks like it's from my misuse of `resize()` in allocating a new `vector` in 2D `vector`, from my misuse of `back()` in `vector`, or from updating a reference variable.

I wrote a simpler code that contains similar problem in my original program for demonstration:

```
int main() {

    vector<vector<int>> A(1);
    vector<int> &recent = A.back();

    recent.emplace_back(50);
    cout << A.back()[0] << endl; //prints 50

    A.resize(2);
    A[1] = vector<int>();
    cout << A.size() << endl;    //prints 2
    recent = A.back();
    cout << A[1].size() << endl; //prints 0
    recent.emplace_back(20);     //Segmentation fault occurs!!
    cout << A[1][0] << endl;
}
```

Segmentation fault occurs when I tried to `emplace_back(20)`, although in my original program it doesn't throw any error and doesn't `emplace` the element either.

Possible cause of problem, in my opinion is:

1. I used `resize()` to allocate a new `vector` after the current last position of the 2D vector `A`, because I didn't know how to `emplace_back()` an empty vector.

2, 3. In `recent = A.back();`, I'm not sure if I am updating the reference variable(defined as `vector<int> &recent`) correctly, and if `back()` gives the correct reference to the newly allocated vector at the end of the 2D vector `A`.

The logic looked perfectly fine, but obviously I am doing something wrong.

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do instead?

Comment: ` A[1] = vector<int>();` can you explain what this line does? Because `resize` calls constructor by iteself.

Comment: @Satus I know. I added that expression just to see if it works with it. It didn't work with or without it.

Comment: `A.back()` already returns a reference that tracks the last element. Why add another layer?

Comment: @TemplateRex the variable name for 2D vector in my program was too lengthy and I wanted to give a meaningful name to the last element in it.

Comment: then just add a reference with a short name to track the entire 2D vector, and access the `.back()` member of that shorthand: `auto& vec_ref = my_long_vector_vector; vec_ref.back();`.

Comment: I added an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References in C++ cannot be "updated". The call to `resize` may (and likely will) invalidate any reference to the original content of the vector. Thus `recent` is a dangling reference after `A.resize(2);`.

When creating the initial `A` here

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> A(1);
```

the outer vector is required to be able to store one single vector.
If you add another `std::vector<int>` to `A` the first element of `A` is likely to move to another memory location. Since `recent` will always refer to the old memory location you see the segfault.

See '[c++ Vector, what happens whenever it expands/reallocate on stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299951/c-vector-what-happens-whenever-it-expands-reallocate-on-stack/17302443#17302443)' for how vectors work.

On the question how to circumvent this:
If you know the size of the vector in advance you could use `reserve` to prevent the vector `A` from reallocating its contents. You'd nevertheless face the problem that references cannot be "reassigned". You can always use `A.back()` to refer to the last element.

You can use a function taking a reference argument which will be bound upon calling the function:

```
void do_stuff(std::vector<int> & recent)
{
  // do stuff with recent
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>> A;
while (condition)
{
  // add whatever to A
  A.emplace_back(std::vector<int>{});
  // do stuff with last element
  do_stuff(A.back());
}
```

Another way to do it is with `scope`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> A(1);
{
  std::vector<int> &recent = A.back();
  recent.emplace_back(50);
  std::cout << A.back()[0] << std::endl; //prints 50
  A.resize(2);
} // recent goes out of scope here

std::cout << A.size() << std::endl;    //prints 2
{
  std::vector<int> &recent = A.back(); // another recent indepedant of first one
  std::cout << A[1].size() << std::endl; //prints 0
  recent.emplace_back(20); 
  std::cout << A[1][0] << std::endl;  // prints 20
}
```

Comment: Is there any workaround for this? I am doing this in a while loop and want to keep a reference to the last vector in 2D vector.

Comment: Use pointer or simply `A.back()` without putting it into reference?

Comment: I try to minimize use of pointers. Does this seem like a proper situation to use a pointer?

Comment: @user2418202 Use `std::list` instead of `std::vector` if you insist on using pointers and/or references to existing items in a resizeable container.

Comment: Thank you. I just used the scope idea. The while loop contained a lot of `if`-`else if`, and I defined reference variable `recent` separately at scopes in which I will use the variable many times.

Answer (score 3):

Let's step through the code line by line.

```
vector<vector<int>> A(1);
vector<int> &recent = A.back();
```

Here we create a `vector` with one default-constructed `vector<int>` as its contents. We then bind a reference to the last and only element.

```
recent.emplace_back(50);
cout << A.back()[0] << endl; //prints 50
```

We now emplace `50` into the sole vector and print it.

```
A.resize(2);
```

Now we resize the `vector`. If space needs to be reallocated, *all iterators, pointers and references to the contents are now invalid*.

```
A[1] = vector<int>();
cout << A.size() << endl;    //prints 2
```

This is fine, as there is enough space in `A`.

```
recent = A.back();
```

**BANG**

This assignment doesn't rebind `recent`, it tries to assign `A.back()` to the referencee. If space was reallocated for `A`, `recent` is no longer a valid reference, so we run off into the realm of undefined behaviour.

Quite honestly, using `A.back()` directly rather than maintaining a reference to it is probably your best bet. If you absolutely want to hold some kind of reference to the end, this is a reasonable use of a non-owning pointer.

Comment: I didn't use A.back() directly because in my original program it would be `keys_in_transaction.back()` and pretty lengthy, and I wanted to give a name like `recent_keys`. Should I use something like `shared_ptr<vector<int>> recent = shared_ptr<vector<int>> (A.back());` even if I am not very good at using smart pointers or pointers?

Comment: You shouldn't use a `std::shared_ptr`, because that denotes ownership of the object. A raw pointer is more suitable.

Comment: @user2418202 You should neither use a `shared_ptr` nor a raw pointer.

Answer (score 2):

From the discussion in the comments, it appears that your original problem was:

```
vector<vector<int>> very_long_name_that_cannot_be_changed;
```

and that you want a shorthand notation to access the last element of this:

```
auto& short_name = very_long_name_that_cannot_be_changed;
short_name.resize(100);             // will expand the vector, but not change the reference
short_name.back().emplace_back(20); // presto, quick accesss to the last element.
```

This is proof against resizing, because the reference just tracks the vector, not its last element.