# Why sizeof returns different value on different IDE?

Tags: c++, sizeof

Why the following code returns 12 in codeblocks 13.12 and 20 in visual studio 2010? I am also confused why it returns any other value than 0 as vectors are dynamic and i have not pushed back any elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class c
{
public:
    vector<int>v;
    c()
    {
        v.clear();
    }
};
int main() {
    int m;
    c ob;
    cout<< sizeof(ob);

}
```

Comment: Think about how you would implement a vector, and you may understand why the size is very unlikely to ever be 0. As a minimum it would contain, for example, a pointer and a counter. Remember, sizeof a vector is not the same as sizeof the vector contents.

Comment: btw its the compiler that compiles your code, not the IDE

Comment: Also this is not because a vector doesn't have any element that it doesn't consume space. I don't know the implementation of vector but it might have its own internal attributes : pointer to the stored data (even if it's just NULL), the number of elements (even if it's just 0),...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299951/c-vector-what-happens-whenever-it-expands-reallocate-on-stack/17302443#17302443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `sizeof` operator shows you the *in-memory size (in bytes)* of the object representation of given type. Considering that the `vector` container consists not only of data (there might be counters, pointers, etc) then the exact size in memory depends on implementation in compiler you are using.

And in your case there are different compilers depend on chosen IDE:

- Visual C++ in Visual Studio
- MinGW (most likely) in CodeBlocks

If you want to know the exact size (in bytes) of *data* inside your `vector` then you can use following method:

```
int vector_size = sizeof(int) * v.capacity();
```

Comment: It is not really the IDE as the original question assumed, but it is also not the "compiler".  It is the std library headers that are responsible for the variation in sizeof std::vector.  That size might also differ between debug and release builds (because of conditional compilation in those headers).  If you use a compiler, such as ICC, without its own headers, or you use any compiler with the headers shipped with a different compiler, most such size changes follow the headers, not the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a matter of IDE but of compiler as comments says.

Whatever, `obj` is certainly not of size 0, because it contains at least a vector. An empty `vector` simply does not contains any element, but this does not means that the memory it uses is 0, it may have some hidden necessary attributes.

Different sizes may be due to : different padding applied by different compilers, and different implementations of vectors on different development environments.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::vector` can be implemented in different ways, but all of them require three data members. One possibility is equivalent to

```
template<typename Tp>
class vector
{
  typedef Tp*pointer;
  pointer begin_memory, end_used, end_allocated;
};
```

which corresponds to `sizeof(vector)=3*sizeof(pointer)`. However, alternatively you can replace either or both of `end_used` and `end_allocated` with members of type `size_t`. This layout and the hardware dependent `sizeof(pointer)` and `sizeof(size_t)` determine the `sizeof(vector)`: the size in memory used by a `std::vector<>`.

On a 32bit system, it's common to have `sizeof(pointer)=sizeof(size_t)=4` and hence `sizeof(vector)=12`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add something regardless of the `vector`. Even `int` has not a universal size among all compilers(or what you called an IDE).
`int` is at **least** 4 bytes. So, it may be larger.