# Do I need to delete a vector?

Tags: c++

I am defining a vector as a private variable of a class Grid. Class Points has only two instance vars that are all ints but the number of points will only be known when I read this in from the file, so I guess I have to make Points dynamically with new which means I have to destroy them later.  Did I initialize constructor correctly and When writing a destructor for Grid do I need to write a destructor for vector like this: ~vecotr() or with delete or using iterator?

```
class Grid{
public:
  // initialize vector with 3 points with val 0.
  Grid(vector<Points> v) : vector<Points>(3, 0) {};  // is this right


// first option
  ~Grid() {
    ~vector<Points>();  // not sure how to destroy vector<Points>;
  }

// second option
  ~Grid() {
     delete v_points;
  }

// third option
  ~Grid() {
     for (vector<Points>::iterator it = v_points.begin(), 
          vector<Points>::iterator it_end = v_points.end(); it != it_end; it++)
  }

private:
  vector<Points> v_points;
};
```

Which option should I use and did I initialize constructor correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If object is not allocate with `new`, you do not need to explicitly destroy it.
The member objects will be automatically destroyed in the reverse order of their declaration.  In your case there is no need to even create a destructor as the automatic one will suffice.

If for some reason you do have member objects allocated with new, you also have to create custom copy construct and assignment operator otherwise you run into troubles of sharing the same member object across multiple instances.

Comment: @Anycom Well I will be calling new Points to create each new point so then do I use the third option?

Comment: @Napalidon, Is there a specific reason for that instead of just doing it without `new`?

Comment: @Napalidon I dont think you want to be using new to populate points, unless Point is a pointer (which my hunch is it is not).

Comment: @Napalidon when I started learning C++ i also wanted to `new` this and that, because books stressed it so much.  In practice, I rarely use new/delete.

Comment: @Anycorn Point is a class that has info about the point like int x, int y, and int weight. So I am a little confused, if I have a file that tells me this info for each point and I don't know ahead of time how many points this file contains how can I populate the list without "new"?

Comment: @Napalidon eg `Point p; p.x = ...; v_points.push_back(p);` push_back method will append a copy in v_points and the temporary point will be automatically destroyed.

Comment: @Napalidon, Perhaps [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=46abaf1a12) might make it more clear. Since it isn't shown anymore, the build command is `clang++ /*args*/ main.cpp && echo "1 10 5" > test.txt && ./a.out`.

Comment: @Napalidon, It just creates a file on the fly to use with the file input you see in the code and the file contains `1 10 5`. Other than that, it compiles and runs the program.

Answer (score 1):

I will reply because predecessors answered only to the question from topic while you are asking more questions and I will also give some advice. In the remainder of this post we will assume that if `Points` do allocate any dynamic memory, the memory is returned properly when `Points` are deleted.

> Class Points has only two instance vars that are all ints but the
>   number of points will only be known when I read this in from the file,
>   so I guess I have to make Points dynamically with new which means I
>   have to destroy them later.

This comes with contradiction to what you actually do here

```
class Grid{
public:
  // initialize vector with 3 points with val 0.
  Grid(vector<Points> v) : vector<Points>(3, 0) {};  // is this right

private:
  vector<Points> v_points;
};
```

because you create vector without `new`. However this might be OK if we assume that you first get number of `Points` and then you are about to create a Grid. `std::vector` is not C array and might be easily resized, assigned and gives much more flexibility. You do not have to create it on heap because you are afraid about size: vector elements are [always](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8036528/1141471) created on heap, it is just a vector itself that is (if it is) on stack. And this is often exactly what we want (see i.e. [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)). The proper way to initialize a vector would be then

```
class Grid{
    public:
      // initialize vector with 3 Points with val Points(0)
      Grid(vector<Points> v) : v_points(3, Points(0)) {};

    private:
      vector<Points> v_points;
};
```

Note, we do it in initialization list. For POD class members, it makes no difference, it's just a matter of style. For class members which are classes, then it avoids an unnecessary call to a default constructor.

> Did I initialize constructor correctly and When writing a destructor
>   for Grid do I need to write a destructor for vector like this:
>   ~vecotr() or with delete or using iterator?

You don't initialize constructor, rather in constructor initializer list you initialize class members. Since vector is not allocated with `new`, you will not `delete` it (call `delete`). It will be destroyed automatically when `Grid` is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

```
// fourth (and correct) option:
~Grid() {
}
```

Or just leave out the destructor entirely; the compiler-generated destructor will do the right thing here.

If you create an object with `new` you must delete it. If you don't, you mustn't.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `Points` does not have any dynamically allocated memory. If this is the case then all you need is

```
~Grid() { }
```

If it does then you need to delete that dynamically allocated memory for each item in the vector (or use smart pointers).

Comment: Better to just not put the destructor in at all imo.

Comment: All you need is the implicit destructor, which looks like this:

Comment: I was assuming that the poster had reduced the problem to the bare bones and the destructor would contain other things. Anyway IMHO I like to be explicit.

Comment: @EdHeal if I read form the file that has a number of points, then I guess I have to create each Point dynamically right? So will that mean I need to use the third option?

Comment: @Napalidon, That sounds to me like `Point pt; fin >> pt; v_points.push_back(pt);` in its simplest form.

Comment: @Napalidon - I guess Point is just either 2 or 3 integers - In this case you do not need to dynamically allocate the memory. So Chris answer would be correct.

Comment: @EdHeal I appologize for a silly question but why is it that for some objects I have to use new and if I have only a three int object even though I don't know how many I will have before hand, I don't?

Comment: @Napalidon - The vector template does the handling of the variable size lists for you (something you do not have to worry about). It is called encapsulation and a very useful feature of OOP.