# Should I destroy STL containers in my class's destructor, when the class wraps both a STL container and a pointer?

Tags: c++, stl, destructor

I kind of understand the fact that the wrapped STL containers of a class will be automatically destroyed when an instance of that class goes out of scope. Thus I don't have to write a destructor when the class only wraps STL containers. But what if the class also have to manage some pointer(s)?

Say in some CUDA development, I want a class to handle a device pointer and an STL container as well.

```
class Image{
    private:
        float *data_device;
        std::array<int, 2> shape;
    public:
        // some constructors and methods
        ~Image(){
            cudaFree(data_device);
            // what to do with the STL array?
        }
};
```

In the above case, I need the destructor to free the memory for `data_device`. But should I deal with the STL array? If so, how can I destroy the `shape` properly?

Comment: related/dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523520/do-i-need-to-delete-a-vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can imagine that the closing brace of a destructor additionally has calls to each member's (and base's) destructor, in the reverse order of construction.

As such you don't need to do anything extra to a properly designed member, which all the `std` containers are. But let's back up a little.

> But what if the class also have to manage some pointer(s)?

You shouldn't write such a class. Instead you use a class whose *sole* job is to manage *exactly one* pointer as an alternative to "some pointer". As a bonus, you now don't have to worry about double-free, because `Image` does not have a default copy constructor

```
// cuda Deleter for std::unique_ptr
struct CudaFree
{
    void operator()(float * ptr) { cudaFree(ptr); }
}

class Image{
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<float, CudaFree> data_device;
        std::array<int, 2> shape;
    public:
        Image(/* ? */)
          : data_device(cudaAlloc()/* ? */), 
            shape(/* ? */) 
        {/* ? */}
        // similarly other constructors
        // other members
        // implicit destructor does the right thing
};
```

Answer (score 4):

> But should I deal with the STL array?

No, you shouldn't.

[`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) destructor destroys every element of the array automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You are right to create a destructor to manually tear down anything your class manages.

However, doing so does not prevent everything else from being destructed. Your members will still be automatically destructed *after* the destructor runs; your destructor is *in addition*.

So you've done it right.