# C++ Use of smart pointers inside STL containers

Tags: c++, stl, smart-pointers

What is the benefit of using smart pointers inside STL containers ( vectors, maps etc... ) knowing that these containers manages already the memory ?

Example:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>
```

instead of

```
std::vector<int*>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly you mean?

Comment: std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>

Comment: The `vector` manages the memory for the pointers, not the integers. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8036474/166749).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the objects are pointers it is not enough to manage the memory the pointers occupy. You also need to manage what the pointers point to. It is a good idea to store the objects pointed to instead of the pointers (in case of your example `std::vector<int>` would be appropriate), however, in case you have polymorphic objects that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it when you need to hold an array of references to objects.  That way I can sort an array of references without actually moving the objects around in memory.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
        std::shared_ptr<int> foo(new int(3));
        std::shared_ptr<int> baz(new int(5));
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> > bar;
        bar.push_back(baz);
        bar.push_back(foo);

        std::sort(bar.begin(), bar.end(), [](std::shared_ptr<int> a, std::shared_ptr<int> b)
        {
                return *a < *b;
        });

        for(int i = 0; i < bar.size(); ++i)
                std::cout << *bar[i] << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
3
5
```

Comment: `shared_ptr`s [compare internal pointer values](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp), not their content.