# Dynamically growing vector which is declared static in cpp

Tags: c++, vector, static

I understand that static variables are allocated in the data segment (not in stack and heap).

```
std::map< std::string, testClass*> TestMap;

static TestMap testMapInstance;
```

Here testMapInstance is a dynamically growing map. Where we push testClass which is allocated via new (heap).

How does compiler allocate this static variable and where?
What is the memory limit in this case (how much this map can grow)?

Comment: `testClass` gets allocated in the heap and it's been refered from `TestMap` note you've used `testClass *`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When vectors are allocated, do they use memory on the heap or the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036474/when-vectors-are-allocated-do-they-use-memory-on-the-heap-or-the-stack)

Answer (score 3):

While the `std::map` *object* itself might be in a data-segment, the key-value storage is *not* allocated there.

It simply *can't* be since the number of key-value pairs is not known at compile-time, only on run-time.

Therefore the key-value pairs have to be dynamically allocated of the heap.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably worth reminding yourself that `std::map<K, V>` is actually this:

`std::map<K, V, Pred, Alloc>`

Since you haven't mentioned `Pred` in your map declaration it defaults to `std::less<T>`.

Similarly `Alloc` defaults to `std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >` where `std::pair<const Key, T>` is the implied `value_type` of your map.

It is the class denoted by `Alloc` that determines how and where the values in the map are allocated.

`std::allocator<X>` uses `::operator new` and `::operator delete` to allocate and deallocate memory. Unless you have redefined those, memory will be managed by the heap.

You can override this by specifying your own custom type for `Alloc`. Doing this successfully however is something of a dark art. You may want to read up on it before you try.

ref: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator#Allocator_completeness_requirements

Comment: I would presume that generally, users asking such questions cannot, and should not, write a custom allocator.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is in the static data area, but he `map` will also allocate additional space from the heap when it grows.