# C++ struct memory layout for std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct

For the following struct, since v is a dynamically allocated object, how would the memory alignment work? Is the size of `struct  S` constant, even as the size of v goes? So does v essentially work as a pointer (or some kind of wrapper of a pointer)?

```
struct S {
    ANY_TYPE a;
    std::vector<ANY_TYPE> v;
} s;
```

If the answer is yes to all the above questions, then as the size of v goes, where is the memory of its members stored? Are these considered memory on heap or on stack?

Edit: I see downvotes for this question and realized I should've done more research into std::vector itself. I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036474/when-vectors-are-allocated-do-they-use-memory-on-the-heap-or-the-stack), which made everything clear. Thanks for the answers tho!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When vectors are allocated, do they use memory on the heap or the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036474/when-vectors-are-allocated-do-they-use-memory-on-the-heap-or-the-stack)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`v` is not dynamically allocated.  The `std::vector` itself is part of the `S` object.  `v` does, however, *own* a dynamically allocated buffer.

What this means is that `sizeof(S)` is constant.  It will always be `sizeof(ANY_TYPE) + sizeof(std::vector<ANY_TYPE>) + padding`.

Essentially, `S` will be laid out in memory something like this (possibly with some padding between `a` and `v` to maintain alignment):

```
  S
+---+
|   |
| a |
|   |
+---+
|   |
| v |    dynamically allocated buffer
|   |  +------+------+-----+
| +----> v[0] | v[1] | ... |
|   |  +------+------+-----+
+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise and helpful answer! So can I understand the source of the left arrow in your drawing as a pointer wrapped in the object v?

Comment: Yes, `std::vector` generally contains a pointer to the first element of its dynamically allocated buffer.  (It usually has two other members: its current size and capacity).

Answer (score 0):

`v` is definitely a wrapper of at least a pointer and (depending on the implementation) some other accounting.  The on-stack (or in-array) footprint of `v` will be limited to only those members declared directly within the `std::vector` class, and yes, that means that the size of `v`, and therefore the size of instances of `S`, will be constant.

The number of bytes consumed *on behalf of* `v` (and instances of `S`) will depend on how much *heap* memory is allocated by `v` in the course of its construction and lifetime.

What memory is used for the immediate members of S (including `v`) is determined by the code doing the declaration:

```
void my_func() {
    S s1;          // `s1` and its members `a` and `v` are all on the stack
                   //  ...though `v` will allocate heap memory for its own use
    S* s2 = new S; // `s2` points to a heap-allocated instance of `S`
```