# Is it possible to allocate vectors in the heap but accessing via reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, reference

I have a program using quite a bit of storage (2.5MB) and I store it all in the stack using std::vector.

1. Would it be a good idea to save that in the heap instead and
2. If that is the case is it possible to use functions that take references vector& when the stored types are of vector* (as they are allocated with new)?

Comment: A `std::vector` *does* store everything you put into it on the heap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When vectors are allocated, do they use memory on the heap or the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036474/when-vectors-are-allocated-do-they-use-memory-on-the-heap-or-the-stack)

Comment: I am happy to have this problem solved then. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Unlike `std::array`, `std::vector` does not store elements inside itself, it always allocates storage on the heap (unless you use a custom allocator). Your 2.5 MB go into the heap, and only `std::vector` itself (a couple of pointers and the size, 12/24 bytes, typically) is allocated on the stack.
2. You can do it:

   ```
   void foo(std::vector<T>&);

   std::vector<T>* vec = ...;
   foo(*vec);
   ```

**Edit.** I found a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036474/when-vectors-are-allocated-do-they-use-memory-on-the-heap-or-the-stack). Voted to close this one.