# How to declare an static std::vector in the heap

Tags: c++, vector, static, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have declared an static vector inside a class:

```
class Algorithm
{
private:
    
    const static std::vector<Algorithm> Cancellations;
}
```

I initialize the vector outside the class:

```
const std::vector<Algorithm> Algorithm::Cancellations =
{
        Algorithm("F z'"), Algorithm("b"),
        Algorithm("b S"), Algorithm("B"),
        Algorithm("f z'"), Algorithm("B"),
        Algorithm("S b"), Algorithm("B"),
        Algorithm("z' f"), Algorithm("B"),
        Algorithm("f b"), Algorithm("B F"),
        Algorithm("F S"), Algorithm("B z"),
        // Many more algorithms
};
```

Everything works fine, but I have a warning because this vector is too big for the stack, and suggest me that I should move it to the heap, so I change the declaration:

```
class Algorithm
{
private:
    
    const static std::vector<Algorithm>* Cancellations;
}
```

And the initialization:

```
const std::vector<Algorithm>* Algorithm::Cancellations = new std::vector<Algorithm>
{
        Algorithm("F z'"), Algorithm("b"),
        Algorithm("b S"), Algorithm("B"),
        Algorithm("f z'"), Algorithm("B"),
        Algorithm("S b"), Algorithm("B"),
        Algorithm("z' f"), Algorithm("B"),
        Algorithm("f b"), Algorithm("B F"),
        Algorithm("F S"), Algorithm("B z"),
        // Many more algorithms
};
```

Everything works fine again, but the warning is still there.

As I read here: [When vectors are allocated, do they use memory on the heap or the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036474/when-vectors-are-allocated-do-they-use-memory-on-the-heap-or-the-stack), if the vector isn't declared static the data should already been stored in the heap in the two cases. Why when I declare a vector static is stored always in the stack? Or I am missundertanding something?

Here is the information about the warning: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6262?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(C6262)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-160

Thank you.

Comment: That warning sounds bogus for two reasons: an `std::vector`'s size is constant because its contents are dynamically allocated, and a static class member variable is *not* allocated on the stack anyway...

Comment: "Stack" usage is the `initializer_list`...

Comment: It's not complaining about the vector, it is complaining about all of the temporary objects you create in the initializer list. You might need to store this information in a file, and then read in and initialize the vector with those values at run time.

Comment: I think that the problem come from the temp objects you're using if it is copied or moved they are on the stack , use heap allocation for them

Comment: @NathanOliver What you say makes all the sense. Thank you.

Comment: You could populate it with an immediately-invoked lambda, allowing you to reserve and push-back.