# What is the technical definition of "dynamic storage" in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

Just what the title says, "What is the technical definition of dynamic storage in C++?" I'm curious as to how to discuss dynamic memory allocation on the heap without making any mistakes in my explanation.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181782/why-are-the-terms-automatic-and-dynamic-preferred-over-the-terms-stack-and

Comment: See  [basic.stc.dynamic].

Comment: You asked quite the same question some minutes ago!

Answer (score 1):

From the [The C++ Programming Language: Special Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201700735)

> *Free store*, from which memory for objects is explicitly requested by
>   the program and where a program can free memory again once it is done
>   with it (using `new` and `delete` ). When a program needs more free
>   store, `new` requests it from the operating system. Typically, the
>   free store (also called dynamic memory
>   or the heap) grows throughout the lifetime of a program because no
>   memory is ever returned to the operating system for use by other
>   programs.

Answer (score 0):

[Detailed Explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

The heap is a bunch of memory that can be used dynamically.

> Lets say you want 12kb of memory for an object then the dynamic allocator will look through its list of free space in the heap, pick out a 12kb chunk, and give it to you.

Generally, the dynamic memory allocator (malloc, new, etc.) starts at the end of memory and works backwards.

Comment: There is no requirement for a heap.  There is no specification for where the heap starts nor how it is manipulated.

Comment: Yes there is no enforced pattern but just for explanation purpose we can assume it.