# How much memory does int x[10] allocate?

Tags: c, malloc

Is there any difference in the memory usage of these two code lines?

```
int *a = malloc( 10 * sizeof(int) );
int b[10];
```

The first line should allocate memory for 10 ints and 1 pointer. But I'm not sure about the second. Will that also allocate memory for 10 ints and 1 pointer, or just 10 ints?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simply put:

```
int *a = malloc( 10 * sizeof(int) );
```

Allocates at least `sizeof(int*)` bytes of automatic storage for the pointer `*a`. When `malloc` is called, this will allocate at least `sizeof(int) * 10` bytes of dynamic storage for your program.

On the other hand:

```
int b[10];
```

Allocates at least `sizeof(int) * 10` bytes of automatic storage. There are no pointers here. When you use the name `b` in an expression (example: `a = b`), it decays into a pointer. But `a` is a pointer and `b` is an array. Check this on C FAQ: [C-FAQ Sec. 6: arrays and pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

In the most usual case, "automatic storage" means the "stack", and "dynamic storage" means the "heap". But that's not always true. You may want to read a bit of discussions about this terms in this question: ["Why are the terms “automatic” and “dynamic” preferred over the terms “stack” and “heap” in C++ memory management?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181782/why-are-the-terms-automatic-and-dynamic-preferred-over-the-terms-stack-and).

Comment: It may or may not allocate any memory in the stack for pointer `*a` depending on how the compiler works.  If you use `&a` anywhere, yes, but otherwise all bets are off.

Comment: Thanks. I'll ammend my answer.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Reading again, I may have misunderstood your comment. Could you give me a concrete example?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: How is allocation for `a` handled differently from `b` in terms of *where* the memory is allocated?

Comment: @giusti: The variable can be optimized out, for one thing.

Comment: But that would be true for any variable. Is there anything special about pointers that make allocation any different if you don't take the pointer's address?

Comment: @DietrichEpp "pointer `*a`" <- `*a` is not a pointer - you mean "pointer `a`"

Comment: @immibis: `*a` is how it's declared.  I don't think the wording is confusing.

Answer (score 8):

In the first case, `a` itself occupies `sizeof(int *)` bytes of automatic storage, and that points to `10 * sizeof(int)` bytes of dynamic storage.

In the latter case, `b` occupies `10 * sizeof(int)` bytes of automatic storage.  Because `b` is an array, there is no pointer.

So the first case uses more total bytes, but less on the stack (assuming a stack is in use for automatic storage).

If the total number of bytes being used is relatively small, automatic storage is typically fine.  For larger amounts, dynamic storage is preferred.  For stack implementations in particular, having too many automatic variables that are too large can overflow the stack.