# sizeof a really big array

Tags: c, stack, sizeof

Why does this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char big_array[10000000000];
    printf("%d", sizeof(big_array));
    return 0;
}
```

print the output as

```
1410065408
```

instead of **10000000000** ?

If the reason is due to the stack memory not being big enough, at what point does it give runtime error instead of allocating smaller memory?

Comment: Use `"%zu"` as the format string for a `size_t`.

Comment: 10000000000  is roughly 9 gig. Chances are your stack isn't that big and so you've got undefined behavior.

Comment: Usually the stack size is ```1MB``` by default. You tried to allocate more memory than that. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52278866/5821185) to get more familiar with what could be happen in such a scenario.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh "Usually the stack size is 1MB by default. You tried to allocate more memory than that." --> C does not require that memory in `main()` must be one the _stack_.  Even if it is a common memory model, many possibilities exist.

Comment: "Usually the stack size is 1MB by default." That would depend on the OS and other details. And that only if we are talking about desktop PCs. I normally use a stack with 512 bytes for my daily work.

Comment: The numerical limits of integer are often addressed in one of the first chapter of any beginner-level C book. And so everyone who has read one tend to recognize the magic numbers 127, 255, 32767, 65535, 2147483647 and 4294967295.

Comment: @John3136 While that is true, there's no reason for the compiler to allocate any variables at all when generating this program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turn on warnings! You should have gotten a warning that `%d` doesn't match the `size_t` argument you gave it. The format should be `"%zu\n"`. The 1410065408 you're getting is 10000000000 modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, i.e. truncated to 32 bits.

If you actually tried to *use* that array, it would likely crash. (As it is, the compiler is optimizing away the unused array.) That is way too much to allocate on the stack. You need to use `malloc()` for something that big.