# understanding memory allocation nature for a circular buffer implementation

Tags: c++, buffer, heap-memory, circular-buffer, stack-memory

I am trying to understand the memory allocation while using a third party written Ring Buffer implementation.

I referred to two freely available implementations of ring buffer :

1. https://github.com/fbergama/MTCircularBuffer
2. https://github.com/wizard97/Embedded_RingBuf_CPP

I tried to compile the available test programs in the above libraries on Ubuntu 16.04 PC. The libraries are provided with test programs. The test programs compile and I am able to use them successfully.
However, what I want to know and understand is where does the memory for ring buffer elements ( in above libraries) get allocated ? Is it on the stack or the heap ?

Comment: Do you know what [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9181782/212858) allocation looks like in code? There is a keyword (or one of a few C functions) involved - did you search for it in the linked code? What did you find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where does the memory allocated for elements of ring buffer in above libraries get allocated ? Is it on the stack or the heap with the given test programs in the above repositories ?

if you do

```
{
   RingBufCPP<int, 10> rb1;
   RingBufCPP<int, 10> * rb2 = new RingBufCPP<int, 10>;
   ...
}
```

*rb1* is on the stack and the value of *rb2* on the heap

You have the choice because the size if known and there is no *new* to allocate the buffer in the implementation

---

But in `MTCircularBuffer( size_t size )` there is a *new*, a part is allocated in the heap whatever you do `MTCircularBuffer<int> rb1(10);` or `new MTCircularBuffer<int>(10);`

Comment: Does this mean that with the given test program e.g., https://github.com/wizard97/Embedded_RingBuf_CPP/blob/master/examples_no_arduino/test.cpp, it is on the stack ?

Comment: @tauseef_CuriousGuy yes it is, the buff is the attribute `Type _buf[MaxElements];`