# What strategy should be used when trying to point to automatic objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, memory-management, reference

I am developing a relatively large library (~13000 lines) as a personal utility library. It uses exclusively STL containers and smart pointers for memory management - but now I find myself in a situation where I could see going for normal pointers due to an apparent lack of an obvious solution in STL. I would like to maintain a modern C++ style, though.

Here's my [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

Struct `Foo` - a `int`-wrapper struct displaying which member functions were called.

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int x) {
        this->x = x;
        std::cout << "constructor\n";
    }
    Foo(const Foo& other) {
        this->x = other.x;
        std::cout << "copy constructor\n";
    }
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "destructor\n";
    }

    int x;
};
```

Looking at `main` I create an automatic instance of `struct Foo`:

```
int main() {
    Foo foo{ 0 };
    std::cout << "\nfoo.x : " << foo.x << "\n\n";    
}
```

output >

```
constructor

foo.x : 0

destructor
```

Easy as that. - now if I want to point to `foo` and manipulate its content.

---

Smart pointers like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) won't achieve this effect (apparently!). Using `std::make_unique<T>()` (/ `std::make_shared<T>()`) will dynamically allocate memory and only copy the value:

```
Foo foo{ 0 };
std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr = std::make_unique<Foo>(foo);

ptr->x = 2;

std::cout << "\nptr->x : " << ptr->x << '\n';
std::cout << "foo.x  : " << foo.x << "\n\n";
```

output >

```
constructor
copy constructor

ptr->x : 2
foo.x  : 0 // didn't change  

destructor
destructor
```

So that's not working. However, their `void reset(pointer _Ptr = pointer()) noexcept` member function allows to directly assign a pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr;
Foo foo{ 0 };

ptr.reset(&foo);

ptr->x = 2;

std::cout << "\nptr->x : " << ptr->x << '\n';
std::cout << "foo.x  : " << foo.x << "\n\n";
```

output >

```
constructor

ptr->x : 2
foo.x  : 2

destructor
destructor //crash
```

But crash! `foo` get's deconstructed normally and than `std::shared_ptr` *also* wants to deconstruct its already deconstructed dereferenced value.

> HEAP[main.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap(...)

---

Using a const pointer:

```
Foo foo{ 0 };
Foo* const ptr = &foo;

ptr->x = 2;

std::cout << "\nptr->x : " << ptr->x << '\n';
std::cout << "foo.x  : " << foo.x << "\n\n";
```

output >

```
constructor

ptr->x : 2
foo.x  : 2

deconstructor
```

- 1 allocation, 1 deallocation.
- no copying.
- actually manipulating the value.

So far the pointer feels like the best option.

---

I am just looking for a way to point to automatically allocated objects. So far it seems surprisingly difficult without going back to plain pointers.

I provided one solution by myself - which is using [`/*const*/ std::reference_wrapper<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper). (feel free to correct me about this solution)

But I am not sure what's the best strategy. The pointer? the `std::reference_wrapper` maybe? Did I made a mistake with using `std::shared_ptr` / `std::unique_ptr`?

**Is there a better, more straightforward STL class?**

Comment: _Why_ do you want pointer semantics? For what purpose? You haven't actually told us what you're trying to do.

Comment: You could also use a custom deleter instead? Also quite dangerous to have some objects allocated on the stack and others on the heap!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Passing the same resources through multiple layers of classes. So far they're all allocated on the heap (because that makes it easy to pass them via `std::shared_ptr`) but I think it's bad design. So I want it to be on the stack, no dynamic allocation.

Comment: Why do you think it's bad design?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because it doesn't have to be on the heap, I suppose. It just feels like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146094/why-should-i-use-a-pointer-rather-than-the-object-itself) example, overall.

Comment: `observer_ptr`?

Comment: You haven't fully specified your goal, but from I can tell, it matches the use cases described in the accepted answer there. People use dynamic allocation a lot when they don't need to, but that doesn't mean you should avoid it at all costs.

Comment: By the way: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9181782/560648

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ! thanks for the link

Comment: @StoryTeller `observer_ptr` looks interesting, too bad it's experimental

Comment: It's also nothing more than a raw pointer with a fancy name, really

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I am not sure what's the best strategy. The pointer?

Possibly. If you need to point at an object, then pointer can be a good choice.

Reference might be another:

```
Foo foo{ 0 };
Foo& ref = foo;
ref = 2;
```

If a reference is sufficient, then it's usually preferable to a pointer.

> Did I made a mistake with using `std::shared_ptr` / `std::unique_ptr`?

Yes. You took ownership of an automatic variable. That's a no-no.

In the first example you made a copy of an object, expecting modification of the copy to affect the original.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was something wrong with my smart pointers. And yes right now it feels like the right thing to do is just using pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Hedging my bets a little on this one, as your goal is unclear.

---

If you want to pass resources around strongly, in a manner that makes ownership and lifetime clear, then a smart pointer is the appropriate way to do that. The standard library already provides them, so just use them.

You've discovered already that this is largely incompatible with objects of automatic storage duration (what you've called "on the stack"). You can work around it with a custom no-op deleter, but honestly why? You're just making life way too complicated for yourself. When you create objects in this manner, the ownership and lifetime are chosen for you, and easy to get wrong (dangling pointers, folks!).

Just have `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` dynamically allocate your `Foo`s for you, and use the resulting smart pointer in the usual manner.

---

However, obviously we cannot see your design, nor do we know much about it.

If all you need to do is pass references to objects to functions, which will *do a thing* then return, then simply do that!

```
void bar(const Foo& foo)
{
    // do stuff
}

int main()
{
   Foo foo;
   bar(foo);
}
```

Comment: +1 Yes I could just pass it through, but that would add a lot of Arguments to all functions and I would rather save the pointer somehow. In the first paragraph you're saying that I should in fact allocate everything dynamically. So in the mcve that `foo` would be dynamically allocated and `ptr` would just point to the resource?

Comment: @StackDanny I honestly can't make a firm recommendation without knowing _what you're trying to do_. "but that would add a lot of Arguments to all functions" Why? What sort of arguments? How is a reference "more arguments" than a pointer? Again, unclear.

Comment: Also having all your objects on the stack limits the number of them. I hope you don't expect to store MBs of data on the stack.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well I have multiple objects that need to be passes through. And that's a graphical pipeline, so alot of functions in many loops. In my example the "application" class controls the states of the program and shares it's resources with them. So each loop call & update call & draw call: <resources, states vectors, communication flag vectors, display class> need to be given as arguments. which feels ugly.

Comment: What does that have to do with whether you pass pointers or references, or allocate dynamically?

Comment: I hope I can clarify a bit - I am not passing anything through arguments right now, each class a pointer to these objects. But the *initial* objects (the superclass that creates these objects), are also dynamically allocated. So I want to make these initial objects automatic and go  `child_class_resource_ptr = &automatic_resource` instead of `child_class_resource_ptr = dynamic_resource_ptr`. So far my impressiong is that it doesn't really matter (but I've seen also the other arguments)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, not getting it at all. There seem to be rationales and constraints and arguments missing from your descriptions. Maybe it's just me. Hopefully someone else can help you better.

Comment: I just think that changing from using pointers to passing by reference would completely turn over every design aspect of my classes. But in the end these additional informations (about my library) I doubt are neccessary so I didn't mention them. If I find a suitable solution to the mcve it will work for my complicated real world case.

Comment: If your objects have automatic storage duration then switching from pointers to references shouldn't change anything at all. What "turn over" aspect do you envisage? I think you need to give some examples - your MCVE should demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 0):

[`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
Foo foo{ 0 };
std::reference_wrapper<Foo> ref = foo;

ref.get().x = 2;

std::cout << "\nref.x : " << ref.get().x << '\n';
std::cout << "foo.x : " << foo.x << "\n\n";
```

output >

```
constructor

ref.x : 2
foo.x : 2

deconstructor
```

Which behaves just like a pointer. Well, looking at it's implementation it *is* a pointer:

```
template<class _Ty>
    class reference_wrapper
        : public _Weak_types<_Ty>::type
    {
public:
    /*...*/
private:
    _Ty * _Ptr; //<---
    };
```

For a `pointer const` effect (*`Foo* const`*) it can be declared as a `const std::reference_wrapper<Foo>` - disallowing any change of its pointer address.

```
Foo foo{ 0 };
const std::reference_wrapper<Foo> ref = foo;
Foo foo2{ 2 };
ref = foo2; //error
```

> Error C2678   binary '=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::reference_wrapper' (or there is no acceptable conversion)