# C++ delete base or dynamic_cast pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2015, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

In a situation where we have a derived class object binded to the base class pointer `bPtr`, and a derived class pointer `dPtr` pointing to the same object via `dynamic_cast<D*>`, what is the proper way to cleanup the resources?

```
class B {
public:
    B() { cout << "B_ctor" << endl; }
    virtual ~B() { cout << "B_destructor" << endl; }
    virtual void foo() { cout << "B_foo()" << endl; }
};

class D : public B {
public:
    D() { cout << "D_ctor" << endl; }
    ~D() { cout << "D_destructor" << endl; }
    void foo() { cout << "D_foo()" << endl; }
};   

int main() 
{ 
    B * bPtr = new D;
    D * dPtr = dynamic_cast<D*>(bPtr);
    bPtr->foo();
    dPtr->foo();
    //delete bPtr;
    delete dPtr;
}
```

I chose to delete `dPtr`. I can also choose `bPtr`. Whenever I do both VS2015 compiler flashes an error. So my question is what is the standard way to deal with given situation?

Also, whenever I change my code to

```
D d;
B * bPtr = &d;
D * dPtr = dynamic_cast<D*>(bPtr);
```

I can't delete neither of pointers. The program just aborts. Why?

Comment: You should not delete  either pointer. It's Undefined Behavior to do so. Only delete memory you allocated with `new`. `bPtr` and `dPtr` point to an object in the automatic storage. If you don't know what that is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181782/why-are-the-terms-automatic-and-dynamic-preferred-over-the-terms-stack-and

Comment: You need to be more specific than "flashes an error".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two pointers to a single object. If the object was created with `new` then you must destroy it with `delete`. If it was not, as in your second example, then it's an error to use `delete`.

Since there was only one `new` you should have exactly one `delete` to destroy it. It does not matter which pointer you use, since they are copies of each other and the destructor is declared `virtual`. If the destructor was not virtual, you would need to delete the exact pointer type of the object that was created with `new`.

Answer (score 4):

`D d` defines an [Automatically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) allocated variable. It is automatically disposed of when it goes out of scope. You do not need to `delete` it and since it was not allocated with `new` you cannot `delete` it.

Only `delete` what you `new` and `delete[]` what you `new []`. If you didn't do either don't `delete` it. If you didn't allocate a variable, check the documentation for the function that provided the variable to see how to properly dispose of it.

Additional helpful reading: [Why are the terms "automatic" and "dynamic" preferred over the terms "stack" and "heap" in C++ memory  management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181782/why-are-the-terms-automatic-and-dynamic-preferred-over-the-terms-stack-and)