# Does the class object grows in size as its private members grow?

Tags: c++

I am writing a class for my SLAM algorithm and this is my first large C++ project!
I do remember that `std::unique_ptr` should be used when I want to keep some object which should have a dynamic memory, one owner and a long lifetime. So when designing a specific class which its object is being created only once and should have a global lifetime (it is the core class object that holds the map). So my idea was to create the std::unique_ptr which will hold that object:

```
class Backend
{
private:
    std::vector<double> values;
    /// some members
public:
    Backend() : values{0} {}
    ~Backend(){}
    // some functions
};

auto backend_ptr = std::make_unique(Backend());
```

So my question is: Does the size of `backend_ptr` will grow if I will increase the size of its private member `values` overtime? And with your suggestion, do I even need this `unique_ptr` at all?

Comment: It is not possible to increase size of `values` member. It is defined at compile time and is not related to the value returned by `values.size()`. At the same time size of `backend_ptr` is not related to the size of `Backend` and is defined at compile time as well.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what yoou're asking about. An expression like `sizof(Backend)` will be stable, and determined at compile time.

Comment: @VTT I thought vector has non-static memory which can increase or shrink overtime

Comment: ***Does the size of backend_ptr will grow if I will increase the size of its private member values overtime?*** No, this is a compile time constant.

Comment: ***I thought vector has non-static memory which can increase or shrink overtime*** The vector can allocate the data it has on the heap will but that has nothing to do with the size of `Backend` or `backend_ptr` or even the sizeof `values`.

Comment: @Edmund Yes, it has. But it does not effect size of vector object, or size of objects containing that vector as a field or size of objects wrapping a pointer to the object containing that vector as a field.

Comment: @drescherjm I see, so that is just another memory allocation which is runtime?

Comment: The vector will contain a pointer to dynamically allocated memory. The size of the pointer does not change.

Comment: @VTT Ok, so in that case declaring a unique_ptr is totally unnecessary in my case?

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah, now I understand what you are saying

Comment: Do yourself a favor and read a good [C++ Book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You'll save a ton of time (seriously).

Comment: @rustyx Ok, cheers. I do read books about C++ but when I think I got a good grasp of it sometimes I get another view of topics over SO and it gets me confused

Comment: Probably. Also it should've been `std::make_unique<Backend>();` otherwise there will be an unnamed temporary `Backend` object.

Comment: I did make one mistake in my comments above. The mention of the word **heap**. Officially c++ does not mention a heap instead it has **dynamic storage duration** see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181782/why-are-the-terms-automatic-and-dynamic-preferred-over-the-terms-stack-and

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of the object is determined during the compilation and has nothing to do with the dynamically allocated memory of your `std::vector values`. This is because during the compilation, your compiler will allocate a fixed memory for the pointers which will point to your variables and objects. So in your case, the pointer to your `std::vector`.

Regarding whether it is feasible to use `std::unique_ptr`, it is hard to say without seeing the overall design but my personal choice would be to avoid in your case.