# c++ copy object to pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers

I have a pointer array of `Word` (objects) and I have to assign another object of type `Word` to this objects array.

Using this two lines of code I put the new object `w` inside my objects array (`word`).

```
 Word w = Word(new_word, len);
 this->word[index - 1] = w;
```

Then I print my objects array and everything comes out right

```
for (int k = 0; k < this->len; k++) {
cout << this->word[k].getChars() << endl;
} // End of function 1
```

After "End of function" we return to the main class that call to another function.

This function print the objects array again but now the function does not print the `w` object that I insert in the previous function.

Second function

```
for (int k = 0; k < this->len; k++) {
    cout << this->word[k].getChars() << endl;
} // End of function 2
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how it can be arranged.

Comment: Show a [mcve]. My guess would be that `Word` constructor stores a pointer to local variable, and ends up with a dangling pointer once the function returns. But rather than guessing, you should show the actual definition of `Word`.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is just not enough code to see what's wrong...

Comment: Could be a [Rule of Three violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). I join the others in requesting a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Though it's difficult to be certain (since we don't have the rest of the function to look at), it seems that you may have a [dangling pointer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dangling-void-null-wild-pointers/) issue.

When you declare `Word w = Word(new_word, len);` in your function, you're declaring it as a local variable, placing it on the [stack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/). Adding this to the array doesn't cause any issues *when you're still in the function*, but once you return from where you came, the function's memory - including `Word w` - is destroyed. When you try to access that memory location again by printing it from the array, you're looking for a variable that no longer exists, and thus get undefined behavior.

Luckily, you're using c++, and heap memory management is fairly well supported! I would consider implementing `word` as an array of pointers. If you then try something like this...

```cpp
Word *w = new Word(new_word, len);    //use "new" to create an object on the heap - persistent after you leave the function!
this->word[index - 1] = w;            //make sure this->word is now an array of Word*; it seems to currently be an array of Word
```

...you may find the problem solved. Just don't forget to free it when you're done!

Comment: Pedantic note: You're not likely to ever see an implementation that doesn't use them, but C++ doesn't require stacks and heaps. If someone can figure out how to implement Automatic and Dynamic memory with fairy dust and Care Bear fluff, that's valid C++.

Comment: @user4581301 And thanks to that curiosity-piquing comment, I've learned what [Automatic and Dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182244/7431860) memory is. Developers who read posts with `-Wpedantic` on are more helpful than most people realize!