# How is the following variable allocated?

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
 int *g = new int;
}
```

In the example above, *g is allocated dynamically on the heap and is module-global. Is that correct?
And what about g? Is it also allocated dynamically on the heap and module-global?

Thank you for answering.

Comment: `g` has automatic storage duration.

Comment: Technically the words stack and heap do not exist in the c++  language. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181782/why-are-the-terms-automatic-and-dynamic-preferred-over-the-terms-stack-and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181782/why-are-the-terms-automatic-and-dynamic-preferred-over-the-terms-stack-and)

Comment: Speaking non-technically `g` is just a regular stack allocated variable. That's the thing about pointers, the pointer and the thing it points to are two different things. Beginners often get confused about that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the only variable you have is `g`, which has type `int*`. There is no `g*` or `*g`.

> g is allocated dynamically on the heap ... Is that correct?

Not quiet. Memory allocation will happen on the right side of the `=`. `g` will be *pointing* to this newly allocated memory. You can access the allocated memory using `g`. When the scope ends, `g` will be destroyed *without freeing the memory*.

> module-global?

No. And we don't have module globals in C++. [We have](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) `static`, `automatic`, `dynamic` and `thread`. `g` variable in this case is `automatic`, which basically means it will be destroyed as soon as the scope ends.