# Why pointer object do not get deleted by itself as other objects got deleted at the end of program in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

Why didn't pointer object `point` in below example get deleted at the end of program by itself, as other object `abc` got deleted? But for pointer object I had to delete it myself, why is that?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    string name;

public:
    A(){
        cout << "const called\n";
    }
    ~A(){
        cout << "object deleted\n";
    }
    void setName(string a){
        name =a;
    }
    string getName(){
        return name;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A abc ;
    A* point = new A();
    abc.setName("Shafaat");
    string a =abc.getName();
    point->setName("Muhammad");
    string b = point->getName();
    cout << "name: "<<a << endl;
    cout << "name: "<<b << endl;
    delete point;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: learn difference from `stack` and `heap` allocation

Comment: Please instead learn the difference between automatic and dynamic lifetimes (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182244/212858)

Comment: The *pointer* does indeed get destroyed, just like any other stack-object does.  The *object that the pointer points to*, on the other hand, was allocated on the heap, not on the stack, and therefore it is the programmer's responsibility to delete it (unless you are using a smart-pointer like std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr; those have destructors defiend that will handle the heap-deletion for you automatically)

Comment: Good reading: [Why are the terms “automatic” and “dynamic” preferred over the terms “stack” and “heap” in C++ memory management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181782/why-are-the-terms-automatic-and-dynamic-preferred-over-the-terms-stack-and)

Comment: Thank you everyone. Found this website useful: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs225/sp2021/resources/stack-heap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer is a reference to a memory address containing data (here, your `A` instance, `point`).

`new` create objects on the heap, which must be managed manually, and return a raw pointer (`point`). Raw pointer must be freed manually (using `delete`).

In your example, the pointer `point` is deleted, but not the memory its referring to, aka, your `A` instance.

If you want to have a pointer that frees its referring data when removed, use dedicated pointer, like [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: Prefer std::unique_ptr unless you actually need shared ownership. shared_ptr is often misused by people that don't understand or refuse to use move semantics. The CPP Core Guidelines say: "Note: Prefer a unique_ptr over a shared_ptr if there is never more than one owner at a time. shared_ptr is for shared ownership. Note that pervasive use of shared_ptr has a cost (atomic operations on the shared_ptr’s reference count have a measurable aggregate cost)."

Answer (score 0):

Each object got lifetime defined. A pointer is an object in automatic and A you created in dynamic memory is an object.

The exit from main function isn't an end of program, it's just that - exit from a function. Objects with process-wide lifetime will continue to live for a while, dynamically allocated ones will stay until deleted