# What is the difference between given two lines of dynamic memory allocation in C++ ? Do they both create 10 sized array?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator

```
int *arr = new int(10);

int *arr = new int[10];
```

It is the code of dynamic memory allocation in c++.
But I am not getting What is the difference between these two.

Comment: the first is not an array. it is only an int with initial value 10.

Comment: I think that any [decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) should have the information needed to answer this.

Comment: In addition to the answers you've gotten, note that you should `delete` the first (non-array) pointer and `delete[]` the second (array) pointer when you're done with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a simple example, let's talk about what happens on the stack.

`int x(10)`
This generally means assigning an value to an `int` named `x`.

`int x[10]`
This generally means creating an array named `x` of 10 elements.

So, when it come to dynamic memory, it's the same thing.

`int* x=new int(10)`
This creates a single integer on the heap and assigns it the value 10.

`int* x=new int[10]`
This creates an array of 10 integers on the heap.

Comment: Handy reading: [Why are the terms “automatic” and “dynamic” preferred over the terms “stack” and “heap” in C++ memory management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181782/why-are-the-terms-automatic-and-dynamic-preferred-over-the-terms-stack-and)

Comment: @user4581301 thanks gotta read that thing tomorrow

Answer (score 5):

`int *arr = new int(10);` allocates heap memory for a single integer, initialized to 10.

`int *arr = new int[10];` allocates heap memory for an array of 10 integers, none of which are initialized to any specific value.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it in mind: The `( )` and `{ }` mainly used for [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) in declarations. And `[ ]` is mainly an indexing operator. So in the first statement, you are trying to allocate an `int` memory with `10` as the initial value. And in the second statement, you are trying to allocate a 10 `int` block array with no default initialization.