# Are the data members in Stack or Heap memory in C++

Tags: c++, object, memory

Just want to know where the data members are in the memory, heap or stack.
Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define p(s) std::cout << s << std::endl

class Fook
{
public:
    char c = 'c';  //
    Fook() {
        p(c);
    }
};

class IDK
{
public:
    int* arr = new int[1]; //
    IDK() {
        Fook fook3;        //
        arr[0] = 90;
        Fook* fook4 = new Fook(); //
        p(arr[0]);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Fook fook1;
    Fook* fook2 = new Fook();
    
    IDK idk1;
    IDK* idk2 = new IDK();

    return 0;
}
```

compiles and gives the expected output

```
c
c
c
c
90
c
c
90
```

in the above code sample the obj `*fook2` and `*idk2` are allocated on heap mem and `fook1` and `idk1` are allocated on stack mem.

1. is `fook2->c` on the stack mem (the obj is on the heap mem)
2. is `*arr` in `idk1` on the heap mem (the obj is on the stack mem)
3. is `*arr` in `idk2` on the heap mem
4. is `*fook4` in *ctor* of `idk1` on the heap mem
5. is `fook3` in *ctor* of `idk2` on the heap mem
6. is `*fook4` in *ctor* of `idk2` on the heap mem

***To summarize everything,*

Where are the data members of each object created in `int main(int argc, char const *argv[])` in the memory(stack or heap)**

Comment: Member variables are stored in the object, so the only question is where your objects are stored

Comment: Gnn..., *on the stack* and *on the heap* are implementation details... The standard wordings are *automatic* for anything that reaches its end of life at the end of the block where it was defined and *allocated* for anything that will have to be explicitely destroyed. And stack and heap are just the common implementations of respectively automatic and allocated.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Well put

Comment: Handy reading: [Why are the terms "automatic" and "dynamic" preferred over the terms "stack" and "heap" in C++ memory management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181782/why-are-the-terms-automatic-and-dynamic-preferred-over-the-terms-stack-and)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: stacks and heaps are not C++ language concepts, but are implementation concepts. The C++ standard talks about automatic and dynamic storage instead. But for simplicity lets just talk about stacks and heaps.

Typically the `new` operator will put your object on the heap (unless `new` operator is overloaded). Otherwise your object goes to the stack.

> 1. is `fook2->c` on the stack mem (the obj is on the heap mem)

The `c` part of a `Fook` object will be in the same place where the object is. In the `fook2` case it is the heap. Note the subtlety. You said `fook2->c` which is the arrow operator: it actually loads `c` (unless overloaded). So the result lands to wherever the left side of `fook2->c` is.

> 2. is `*arr` in `idk1` on the heap mem (the obj is on the stack mem)

Again: `arr` field on an `IDK` object lives wherever the object lives. In the case of `idk1` we have that `arr` pointer lives on stack. However the thing it is pointing to, i.e. `*arr` lives on the heap (since `new` was used). There's a subtlety here as well: `*` operator actually loads data to wherever the left side is (again: unless overloaded).

> 3. is `*arr` in `idk2` on the heap mem

`idk2` lives on the heap, and thus `arr` pointer lives on the heap. Additionally `*arr` lives on the heap since that's how it was declared via `new` operator.

> 4. is `*fook4` in *ctor* of `idk1` on the heap mem

`fook4` pointer lives on the stack. The data it is pointing to lives on the heap.

> 5. is `fook3` in *ctor* of `idk2` on the heap mem

`fook3` object lives on the stack. Always. It doesn't matter that the constructor was called during `new` initialization of the heap object `idk2`. Constructor is just a function, a bit special, but not really different from other functions. The constructor doesn't even know whether it is called on a heap or stack object, and it doesn't care.

> 6. is `*fook4` in *ctor* of `idk2` on the heap mem

Similarly to (3) and (4) `fook4` pointer lives on the stack, while the data it is pointing to (i.e. `*fook4`) lives on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Basically

- `fook1`: entirely on the stack.
- `fook2`: entirely in the heap.
- `idk1`: the `int*` member will be on the stack, and the one element array it points to will be in the heap.
- `idk2`: the `int*` will be on the heap and the array it points to will also be on the heap.

Comment: This is assuming the system is implemented with stacks and heaps, a fairly safe assumption. But not a guarantee. A suitably skilled wizard could implement automatic and dynamic storage with hamster wheels and an old VHS copy of Robocop.

Comment: point taken but ... idk... i guess my philosophy in answering these kinds of questions is to answer at the level the person seems to be at. this is someone asking about the basics so I give them the basic answer. Much material out there speaks of "the stack" and "the heap" even though it is true that automatic and dynamic storage is the proper terminology.

Comment: The comment is not aimed at you. It's for those who follow. If I had problems with the answer there'd be a downvote.