# Structs in std::map<int,struct> memory leaking?

Tags: c++, std, esp32, stdmap

I have the following struct and map

```
struct dataStruct{
  unsigned long time;
  int32_t ch0;
  int32_t ch1;
  uint8_t state;
  int16_t temp;
  uint16_t vbat;
  int8_t rssi;
  };

std::map<uint32_t,struct dataStruct> uuidData = {};
```

And a loop which waits for new data and fills the map with it. (1)

```
for(;;)
{
    if (data_debug.is_new_data_available())
    {
        uint32_t uuid = data_debug.get_ID();
        uuidData[uuid] = {
            millis(), 
            data_debug.get_data1(), 
            data_debug.get_data2(), 
            data_debug.get_state(), 
            data_debug.get_temperature(),
            data_debug.get_battery_level(),
            data_debug.get_RSSI()
        };
    }
}
```

This works, but when I get data with an existing UUID, my intuition is that the old struct never gets deleted and will eventually leak.

I had an alternative code (2) below that tried to bypass this, but when the UUID was duplicated, the struct was filled with garbage.
Is the code in (1) leaking or c++ automatically frees the space when the struct is no longer needed? (I know this sounds like garbage collection, but i have no idea how c++ handle structs)

(2)

```
    if(uuidData.count(uuid)){
        uuidData[uuid].time = millis();
        uuidData[uuid].ch0 = data_debug.get_data1();
        uuidData[uuid].ch1 = data_debug.get_data2();
        uuidData[uuid].state = data_debug.get_state();
        uuidData[uuid].temp = data_debug.get_temperature();
        uuidData[uuid].vbat = data_debug.get_battery_level();
        uuidData[uuid].time = data_debug.get_RSSI();
    }
    else{
        uuidData[uuid] = {
            millis(), 
            data_debug.get_data1(), 
            data_debug.get_data2(), 
            data_debug.get_state(), 
            data_debug.get_temperature(),
            data_debug.get_battery_level(),
            data_debug.get_RSSI()
            };
}
```

Comment: If `uuid` exists, it is reused. `uuidData[uuid] = { ... };` copies the temporary created by the `{ ... }` into the existing object in the `map`.  The `map` will handle correct destruction and deallocation of the object when `uuid` is removed or the map goes out of scope.

Comment: Why is your intuition that the old struct never gets deleted?

Comment: @NathanPierson Because I never explicity called delete.

Comment: Only `delete` what you `new`. If your code has no `new`, it needs no `delete`.

Comment: Minor note: as you are using C++ rather than C, it is not necessary to write `std::map<uint32_t,struct dataStruct>`. You can simplify that to `std::map<uint32_t, dataStruct>`.

Comment: @user4581301 I believe that my confusion rises on the [struct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) and how the memory is handled. I feel like there is not much information on that aspect.

Comment: If you're concerned about memory leaks, it's easy to test by executing the code in a loop and calling `ESP.getFreeHeap()` or the underlying ESP-IDF functions to confirm whether there's actually a leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down what happens with example 1 (the correct way to do this task )

```cpp
uuidData[uuid] = {
            millis(), 
            data_debug.get_data1(), 
            data_debug.get_data2(), 
            data_debug.get_state(), 
            data_debug.get_temperature(),
            data_debug.get_battery_level(),
            data_debug.get_RSSI()
        };
```

The

```
        {
            millis(), 
            data_debug.get_data1(), 
            data_debug.get_data2(), 
            data_debug.get_state(), 
            data_debug.get_temperature(),
            data_debug.get_battery_level(),
            data_debug.get_RSSI()
        };
```

creates and initializes a temporary `dataStruct` variable, an automatic variable that will only exist until it's no longer needed. When the expression ends, the temporary goes out of scope and is destroyed.

```cpp
uuidData[uuid]
```

looks in `uuidData` for a key that matches `uuid`. If it does not find one, it creates an empty `dataStruct` and maps it to the key. This new `dataStruct` is managed by `uuidData`. Where it comes from and where it goes is not your concern. Once a `dataStruct` mapped to `uuid` exists, a reference to it is returned.

Now we have a reference to an existing `dataStruct` in the map and the temporary `dataStruct`. The `=` simply copies the contents of the temporary on the right into the the object represented by the reference on the left. Whatever was in the object on the left is overwritten but the object is still there and still managed by `uuidData`. It will be properly destroyed and deallocated when it is either removed from `uuidData` or `uuidData` goes out of scope. The temporary is destroyed automatically ([ergo the name Automatic variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181782/why-are-the-terms-automatic-and-dynamic-preferred-over-the-terms-stack-and)) for you when the expression is complete.

There is no possibility for a leak here.