# Why do we use pointer of object when we create a object?

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers

Why do we use a pointer of object when we want to create a new object like this?

```
employee *Steve = new employee();
```

In this case, I want to create an object named `Steve`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class employee{
private:
    char name[40];
    int salary;
public:
    employee(){
        strcpy(name, "unnamed");
        salary = 0;
    }
    char *getName(){
        return name;
    }
};

int main(){
    employee *Steve = new employee();
    cout<<"Name: "<< Steve->getName();
}
```

Comment: In C++ (and unlike in some other OO languages), you don't *have* to use pointers: `employee Steve;` is valid.

Comment: We do that only if we learned some other language first, like Java, or C# and have a mistaken impression that C++ works the same way, where each object must be a pointer. It doesn't, in C++ objects do not have to be always referenced indirectly, via a pointer.

Comment: Read about [dynamic memory allocation](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/). When you use `A* a = new A();`, `a` points to an object, allocated on the heap. `A a;` creates an object on the stack.

Comment: To add to @dan04's comment, in C++ if you write `new` stop and look for a better way - standard library collections, smart pointers etc.  Manually allocating (managing) memory should be a last resort.

Comment: @IvanVenkov Minor niggle: [Heap and stack are an implementation details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9181782/4581301). As far as C++ is concerned dynamic allocations can come from Care Bear blood.

Comment: Keep in mind that `new` and `delete` are advanced tools. You still have to know how they work, but you won't use them often in everyday programming.

Comment: Good question.  I've often wondered why many people post code on this site that is using pointers and doesn't **need** to.

Comment: *Why do we use a pointer of object when we want to create a new object like this?*  That is a good question.  For an **owning** pointer, it'd be better to use a `std::unique_ptr`.  The reason to use a dynamic object with an owning smart pointer is because it will outlive the context of its scope.  An automatic object gets destroyed at the end of its scope.  The code provided creates a dynamic object, but does not destroy that dynamic object... so it has a leak.  And the object does not need to outlive its scope.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat    Part of the problem is quite a few beginners to C++ with a background in other languages (C#, Java, etc) assume that C++ works like those languages so believe (almost) everything has to be initialialised with `new` - so start using pointers prematurely.    Another part of the problem is that a *lot* of (poor quality) introductory texts on C++ introduce and encourage usage of `new` and `delete` before they introduce other facilities of C++ (standard containers, smart pointers, etc) [or never introduce much, if anything, of the standard library beyond iostreams].

Answer (score 7):

*We* do not use pointers when *we* do not need pointers. When *we* want to create an object *we* call a constructor to create an object, but *we* do not use `new` nor raw pointers.

```
employee Steve;
std::cout << "Name: " << Steve.getName() << "\n";
```

If *we* dynamically allocate the object then *we* still do not use `new` or raw poitners, but container or smart pointers.

In bad tutorials and questionable teaching *they* use pointers a lot. Often that is because *they* do not actually aim to teach C++, but rather to teach pointers. In modern C++ the use of raw pointers is limited to rare cases.

There would be more to say about the code you wrote, but I'll leave it at that and refer you to [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).