# Unsure how to declare and then access an int array in heap memory

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

I have a giant array that's being used to temporarily store pixel data (before it's written to a file). I've been having "random" crashes and someone much more proficient with C++ than myself suggested that I should put my pixel array in the heap than stack. These were all new words to me but I've read up and it makes sense but I'm struggling to set this up.

Declaring the heap array:

```
int *heap = new int[MAX_WIDTH * MAX_HEIGHT * 3];
```

This is then used by my Canvas class, which I want to hold a pointer to a specific heap:

```
class Canvas {
    public:
    Canvas(int w, int h, bool fill_transparent, int* heap);
    Canvas();
    
    int width;
    int height;
    
    int* heap;
}

Canvas::Canvas(int w, int h, bool fill_transparent, int* heap) {
    if (w>MAX_WIDTH) w = MAX_WIDTH;
    if (h>MAX_HEIGHT) h = MAX_HEIGHT;
    
    width = w;
    height = h;
    heap = heap;
    
    if (fill_transparent) {
        for(int x=0; x<width; ++x) {
            for(int y=0; y<height; ++y) {
                set(x, y, transparent);
                //heap->pixels[x][y] = transparent;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Creating a new canvas and passing the heap along:

```
Canvas new_texture(int w, int h, int* heap) {

  Canvas canvas(w, h, true, heap);

  // Do some things with it, using set(x,y);

  return canvas;

}
```

And then attempting to set pixel data (Pixel is a struct with {int r, int g, int b}:

```
void Canvas::set(int x, int y, Pixel colour) {
    if (x>=width || y>=height || x<0 || y <0) return;
    
    // Set the heap :C
    *heap[(x * (MAX_HEIGHT*3)) + y] = colour.r;
    *heap[(x * (MAX_HEIGHT*3)) + y + 1] = colour.g;
    *heap[(x * (MAX_HEIGHT*3)) + y + 2] = colour.b;
}
```

This is wrong! I just can't figure out how I should be declaring the array, storing the pointer in a class, and then accessing it. `int *heap[]` makes more sense to me but also doesn't work.

I'm learning on the job, and am really struggling to find an overview of how I should be doing this.

I've tried most variations that I can think of, I'm struggling to get something that works in all three places!

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead.  No muss, no fuss.

Comment: As @NathanOliver said use std::vector, current C++ does not recommend the use of new/delete. (See [R.11 C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete))

Comment: side note: [Why are the terms "automatic" and "dynamic" preferred over the terms "stack" and "heap" in C++ memory management?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9181782/4581301)

Comment: Side note: Someone out there owns the allocation pointed at by `heap`, and it isn't `Canvas`. You have to make absolutely certain that the object `heap` points at outlives `Canvas` and is correctly managed throughout its life. Essentially, you could have a bug anywhere in the code and we can't help with any mistakes not in the bits of `Canvas` you have shown.

Comment: Side note: `if (w>MAX_WIDTH) w = MAX_WIDTH;` -> `w = std::max(w, MAX_WIDTH);`

Comment: If this is for anything else then a learning / hobby project, you should seriously consider using one of the many image manipulation libraries available. Rolling you own code to handle RGB images is not an efficient use of you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would access the dynamically allocated memory using
`heap[y * width * 3 + x * 3 + color]` but it's both inconvenient and error prone.

Your class is also lacking the special member functions to follow [the rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) which makes future bugs very likely.

I recommend using a `std::vector` which will manage the dynamically allocated memory for you and you also store `Pixel`s directly in the `std::vector` instead of just multiplying the number of `int`s needed by 3. The struct and the `transparent` constant could look like this:

```cpp
struct Pixel {
    int r = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int b = 0;
};

// replace with the constant values you want for transparent:
inline constexpr Pixel transparent{255, 255, 255};
```

`int` for the individual channels in `Pixel` may be overdoing it a bit. Consider using a smaller type, like `uint8_t` for example.

In your `Canvas` class, you could create `operator()` overloads for accessing the `Pixel`s, that you then store in a `std::vector<Pixel>`:

```cpp
class Canvas {
public:
    explicit Canvas(size_t h, size_t w, bool fill_transparent);

    Pixel& operator()(size_t h, size_t w);
    const Pixel& operator()(size_t h, size_t w) const;

    size_t Height() const { return height; }
    size_t Width() const { return width; }

private:
    size_t height;
    size_t width;

    std::vector<Pixel> pixels;
};
```

And the implementation of the `operator()` overloads becomes a bit simpler than with your dynamically allocated `int`s. The constructor also tells the `std::vector<Pixel>` how many pixels there should be and if they should be `transparent` or have the default constructed `Pixel`:

```cpp
Canvas::Canvas(size_t h, size_t w, bool fill_transparent)
    : height(std::min(h, MAX_HEIGHT)),
      width(std::min(w, MAX_WIDTH)),
      pixels(height * width, fill_transparent ? transparent : Pixel{}) {}

Pixel& Canvas::operator()(size_t h, size_t w) {
    return pixels[h * width + w]; 
}

const Pixel& Canvas::operator()(size_t h, size_t w) const {
    return pixels[h * width + w];
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Teh67P3s9)

Comment: I hesitate on calling out the lack of support for the rule of three/five/zero because I'm not certain `Canvas` is supposed to own the object at `heap`. Structurally, `Canvas` owning it will probably make the program simpler, but I'd have to see the rest of the program.

Comment: @user4581301 I understand the hesitation but I read the intro in the question a few times and I'm pretty sure that there's no complicated owership scheme going on. It was just OPs trial-and-error that got him into the situation where the `heap` is allocated separately - if I'm correct that is :-)

Comment: >It was just OPs trial-and-error that got him into the situation where the heap is allocated separately - if I'm correct

You are indeed! :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Didn't realise std::vector already used the heap (at least, for its contents). This is great, I was fearing a lot of work for the rest of my codebase but I'm making heavy use of vectors already. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

### Main issue

```
*heap[(x * (MAX_HEIGHT*3)) + y] = colour.r;
```

First of all, syntactically this should be:

```
heap[(x * (MAX_HEIGHT*3)) + y] = colour.r
```

Putting a `*` there is just wrong in this case.

Next if `width < MAX_WIDTH` or `height < MAX_HEIGHT`, then you'd obviously be completely off!

This should be `heap[x*(height + 3) + y]`, not `MAX_HEIGHT`.

And then you're still missing the `3` factor from your `y` term here, so actually this should be

`heap[3*(x*height + y)]`

### General Notes

So this will be part "code review", not just addressing the issue.

```
int *heap = new int[MAX_WIDTH * MAX_HEIGHT * 3];
```

Two things here: In C++ it's way easier to just use `std::vector` when allocating a dynamically sized array; That way you get the memory management part 'automatically'.

```
std::vector<int> heap(MAX_WIDTH * MAX_HEIGHT * 3);
```

Moving on, it'd be a bit weird to allocate the memory outside of the Canvas: You'd normally expect the canvas to "own" the memory, so you'd actually just write:

```
// assuming you have your `heap` member as `std::vector<int>` instead of `int *`.
// we know longer take the 'heap' as a parameter, instead we just construct it directly inside of our object
Canvas::Canvas(int w, int h, bool fill_transparent)
// this : thing is a relatively unique thing to C++, this means
// "initialise this field with this expression"; In C++ class
// member initialisation happens *before* we actually enter the constructor body.
// This is called an initialiser list, you should look that term up for more details
: heap(w * h * 3)
{
  // rest of your constructor code here
}
```

This way you don't need to worry about all this setup *outside* your canvas, and as a bonus you're now only allocating as much memory as you need, not as much memory as you might *maximally* need. There *are* situations where you might want to manage the memory outside the canvas struct, or always allocate the maximum amount of memory you may ever need, but unless you know you need this it's not a good idea to add these complications.

Finally, if your `Pixel` is just a simple RGB struct you could just put that into the array directly, no need to have it "unrolled" into integers unless you *need* to force a particular in-memory representation (while fortunately most C++ implementations have a pretty predictable way they layout structs, *technically* it's unspecified in the C++ standard so if you don't know what implementations you're targeting you unfortunately might *have* to skip this step, but this will be fine for *most* cases):

```
std::vector<Pixel> heap; // inside the class

// in the initialiser list:
: heap(w*h) // note no more *3 here

// and in the method, note we don't have the weird 3* term in here anymore

heap[x*height + y] = colour;
```

Also, while this is more a matter of opinion, `heap` is a bit of a weird name for this. You could just call it `pixels`; then you'd write

```
pixels[x * height + y] = colour;
```

which at least to me seems clearer.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like vectors are the way to go. Heap only ended up outside of canvas because I was.. well.. incredibly confused. My initial array was part of it. I'll move the vector back inside.