# C++: How to implement a pointer to another class as a member?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I want to implement a class "class_B" that contains a pointer to an instance of another class "class_A" so that it can also access its member function. However, I do not know how to implement this. Below you can find my minimum working example. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>


class Class_A
{

public:
  int number_;

  // Here we define the constructor for "Class_A".
  Class_A(int a)
  {
    number_ = a;
  }

  void printNumber()
  {
    std::cout << "The value in Class_A is " << number_ << std::endl;
  }
};


class Class_B
{
public:
    Class_A* class_A_instance;

    // Here we define the constructor for "Class_B".
    Class_B(int b)
    {
      class_A_instance = Class_A(b);
    }
};


int main()
{
  Class_B class_B_instance(3);
  class_B_instance::class_A_instance::printNumber();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pointer has to point to to *something*. What object of `Class_A` do you to point to? Where does it exist?

Comment: I think you need dynamic memory allocation, also your members arent static or are they?

Comment: Why is it a pointer? Do you need to change it to point to different instances dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to initialize your Class_A instance on the heap with new. Then call the non-static member class a instance of Class_B instance:

```
#include <iostream>


class Class_A
{

public:
  int number_;

  // Here we define the constructor for "Class_A".
  Class_A(int a)
  {
    number_ = a;
  }

  void printNumber()
  {
    std::cout << "The value in Class_A is " << number_ << std::endl;
  }
};


class Class_B
{
public:
    Class_A* class_A_instance;

    // Here we define the constructor for "Class_B".
    Class_B(int b)
    {
      class_A_instance = new Class_A(b);
    }
};


int main()
{
  Class_B class_B_instance(3);
  class_B_instance.class_A_instance->printNumber();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're welcome. get familiar with heap and stack allocation and theier scopes. also take into account to accept the answer so others can learn too

Comment: Better to rewrite `class_B`'s constructor to use an initialiser list.   Also, use of dynamic allocation (which you're somewhat incorrectly describing as "making on the heap") is optional, not essential - all that is required is that the value of `class_A_instance` be the *address* of a valid object of type `Class_A`.

Comment: asan detects a bug in this application https://godbolt.org/z/zoK5eGWqo and by the time you know how to fix this bug you will be halfway through a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), to be honest C++ is kind of like a landmine field, you can't go through it by trial and error.

Comment: All of this memory management and lifetime stuff makes more sense if you use the correct terminology: [Why are the terms "automatic" and "dynamic" preferred over the terms "stack" and "heap" in C++ memory management?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9181782/4581301)

Answer (score 2):

A pointer needs to point at something, but you are not assigning the pointer correctly.  You are creating a temporary `Class_A` object and assigning it directly to the pointer, instead of assigning the *address* of that object instead.

Also, you are not calling the `printNumber()` method via the pointer correctly, either.

You would need something more like this:

```
...

class Class_B
{
public:
    Class_A* class_A_instance;

    Class_B(int b)
    {
      class_A_instance = new Class_A(b);
    }

    /* alternatively:
    Class_B(int b) :
      class_A_instance(new Class_A(b))
    {
    }
    */

    ~Class_B()
    {
      delete class_A_instance;
    }
};

int main()
{
  Class_B class_B_instance(3);
  class_B_instance.class_A_instance->printNumber();

  return 0;
}
```

However, a better solution in this particular example would be to simply not use a pointer at all, eg:

```
...

class Class_B
{
public:
    Class_A class_A_instance;

    Class_B(int b) : class_A_instance(b) {}
};

int main()
{
    Class_B class_B_instance(3);
    class_B_instance.class_A_instance.printNumber();

    return 0;
}
```